# Where did the Log4j Log Output Go?

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

I am running a Java class directly which has main(), from Eclipse.

No Web servers running. Only the main() of the class is run. In the main() I have this statement,

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

//...

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

public static void main(String[] args){
try
{
   //...
} catch (Exception e) {
logger.error(e);
}
```

Nothing is shown in the Eclipse Console when the error is encountered. The error log is written, but somewhere else. Where is it written to?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your logging configuration, check your `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml`(which so ever in your case).

Comment: I don't have a log4j.properties. This is not a project, just a direct class. Is it looking for log4j.properties on the classpath?

Comment: By default, the LogManager looks for a file named log4j.properties in the CLASSPATH, so to enable logging you have to add in your classpath